# How to split a string value from angular variable and set it to two html controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular, how to split a variable's two values and set it to two controls.
like var date="3,2".split(',');
The variable 'date' contains data values for a textbox and a dropdown list.

```
<input id="txtDateBox" type="text" ng-model="response" value="3"/>

<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
      <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do here at all.  what kind of variable are you using that has "two values" but isn't an array or object?

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter to split your data.

```
myapp.filter('CommaSplitter', function(){
    return function(value){
        return value ? value.split(',') : undefined;
    }
});
```

Then use it:

```
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-options="'Option ' + option for option in values | CommaSplitter">
</select>
```